# How to access remote telnet server within a docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, telnet

I would like to access the Star Wars Ascii movie from the telnet "towel.blinkenlights.nl" within a Docker Container.

Given this Dockerfile [based on nerdalert](https://github.com/nerdalert/Dockerfiles/blob/master/star_wars/Dockerfile):

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add busybox-extras

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/telnet", "towel.blinkenlights.nl"]
```

With this Docker Build & Run Commands:

```
docker build . -t starwars
docker run --rm -i -P starwars
```

I receive the following error messages:

```
telnet: can't connect to remote host (213.136.8.188): Connection refused
```

I also tried this Run Command with the same Error:

```
docker run --rm --network host -P starwars
```

and change the Dockerfile Baseimage to `bitnami/minideb:stretch` with no success.

How should I change the Dockerfile or the Docker run Command to access a (this) remote telnet server?

Without the Docker Container on my Windows Host system - I can access the telnet server `towel.blinkenlights.nl` easily
[image: Working Putty Connection]

Comment: can you connect to the towel.blinkenlights.nl using telnet from your computer? Looks like it may not be a problem related to docker but may be due to towel.blinkenlights.nl being offline

Comment: @MatteoZanoni Sadly, I can connect perfectly to  `towel.blinkenlights.nl` with the putty telnet client. So unfortunately there isn't the problem.

Comment: can you share the putty configurations you use? I tried connecting from my pc with no success... maybe some telnet configuration differ between linux (alpine) and putty.

Comment: @MatteoZanoni here is the working putty connection https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1yu2.png (also added it within the question)

Which command did you try on your pc?

Comment: I just tried `telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl` and it is not working, I have tried also from online tools (like https://adminkit.net/telnet.aspx or https://telnet-online.net ) and neither can connect. Can you retry now and verify it is working on your pc?

Comment: Very strange on my windows host system the given telenet-address works perfectly :(

Do you know any other working telnet server where I can connect to try out the Dockerfile?

Comment: Windows has a build it telnet server that you can activate, otherwise most SMTP servers allow you to connect to them through telnet (e.g.: `telnet smtp-relay.gmail.com 25`)